# How can I trim an NCHAR field right inside a call to WCF service operation?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

This is the implementation of an operation in a WCF service of mine.  The object `_members` is an EF.  `QueryConstraint` is a data contract that stores `Where` and `OrderBy` data and applies it to the enumeration using Dynamic Linq:

```
public IEnumerable<CustomersDC> GetCustomers(QueryConstraint a_constraint)
{
    var customers = from customer in _members.Customers
                    select new CustomersDC
                    {
                        CustomerID = customer.ID,
                        Email = customer.Email,
                        FirstName = customer.FirstName,
                        LastName = customer.LastName,
                        IsEmailVerified = customer.EmailVerified,
                        AccountingID = customer.AccountingID,
                        IsTaxExempt = customer.TaxExempt
                    };

    return customers.Apply(a_constraint);
}
```

The field `AccountingID` is a hold over from another database. As such it is `nchar` and I'm wanting to trim it in the service.  Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `customer.AccountingID.Trim()`, EF knows how to translate it to sql.

Comment: But what if AccountingID is NULL, which it will be quite often?

Comment: It will be tanslated to `LTRIM(RTRIM(...))` which just returns null if `...` is null. It's different from linq-to-objects.

Comment: I can't accept that as an answer because its just a comment.  Do I then just leave this question unanswered?

Comment: I can convert it to an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `customer.AccountingID.Trim()`. Other than in linq-to-objects this does not throw a null reference exception when `AccountingID` is null, because Entity Framework translates it to `LTRIM(RTRIM( xxx ))` which just returns null if `xxx` is null.

That's why `IQueryable` is called a leaky abstraction, it matters how it is implemented. This can be quite a nuisance, because an apparently harmless modification, adding `ToList()`, can now cause runtime exceptions.